# Global parameter does not work with yarn 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

My env:

```
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Yarn: 3.1.1
- Node: v16.12.0
```

Instruction link: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

When I run command: `yarn global add @vue/cli`
I got error:

```
Usage Error: The 'yarn global' commands have been removed in 2.x - consider using 'yarn dlx' or a third-party plugin instead

$ yarn run [--inspect] [--inspect-brk] [-T,--top-level] [-B,--binaries-only] <scriptName> ...
```

Comment: ... or indeed with yarn 2

Answer (score 4):

Yarn has removed `global` in v2, as per the error message you are getting (see [migration guide](https://www.warp.dev/terminus/update-yarn#upgrading-yarn-1-to-2) from v1 to v2 and v3).

You can use the `@vue/cli` the same as `npx` using `yarn dlx` without installing it globally.

`yarn dlx @vue/cli do_something`

Answer (score 1):

The documentation contains instructions for yarn v1.

Yarn v2 and above no longer supports the use of the global parameter.
You can view their migration guide [here](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration).

You can use yarn dlx everytime you want to run a command with vue.
Alternatively, you can install the vue cli using npm:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```